# asp:CustomValidator functionality

Tags: c#, asp.net

So I have this old asp .net 2.0 app and it has these asp:RequiredFieldValidator's and asp:CustomValidator's on some form controls.

When I turned off javascript in the web browser, I discovered the server/back-end validation was non-existent. After coding up a c# version of all the asp:Validator's for back-end validation I discovered that I could simply call [ValidatorID].IsValid to get whether or not a control's value was valid.

I guess my question is, since I turned off javascript, how does the app know if asp:CustomValidator's associated control is valid? Where and when is that javascript being run? It has got to be the server correct?

Also would the correct/suggested way to add back-end validation simply be to have
if(validator1.IsValid && validator2.IsValid ...) { //isvalid } or is there a way I can see if the entire page is valid? Or a way to group validators so that I don't have to change the code-behind every time I add a validator?

Thanks - Ross

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On server side you can use `if(Page.IsValid)` to check if all validations validated succsfully, if client side validation is turned off, validation is done only on server side.

Refer to [Page.IsValid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.isvalid.aspx) MSDN documentation

Answer (score 1):

Put a breakpoint on each one of your serverside validator functions, then call `if(Page.IsValid)` you will see that your code will go to each function in turn, and stop when it hits the first function that returns false.